# How do I tell React component to change its state when an event is triggered from third party lib?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, createjs

I am using `createjs` to create an canvas, and there is a double click event in this canvas, now I want to tell a React component when the event is triggered, and set state to a variable that defined in the custom function. for example, I want to set the value to 'pose.position' that's in the custom function.

my react component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
const handleEvent = event => {
   console.log(value);
};
useEffect(() => {
const ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
   url
});
const viewer = new ROS2D.Viewer({
   divID,
   width,
   height
});
const nav = NAV2D.OccupancyGridClientNav({
   ros,
   rootObject: viewer.scene,
   viewer,
   serverName,
   continuous
});
setValue(nav.position);

const canvas = divEl.current.children[0];

canvas.addEventListener("dblclick", handleEvent, false);

return () => {
    canvas.removeEventListener("dblclick", handleEvnet);
};
}, []);

return <div id={divID} ref={divEl} />;
```

and the custom function:

```
this.rootObject.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event) {
  // convert to ROS coordinates
  const coords = stage.globalToRos(event.stageX, event.stageY);
  const pose = new ROSLIB.Pose({
     position: new ROSLIB.Vector3(coords)
  });
  // send the goal
  sendGoal(pose);
  that.position = pose.position;
  // that.mouseClick = true;
  console.log("clicked");
  });
  //I do not know how my React component can get this value, so I just return
  return this.position;
```

The problem is the value in component only set once,and the log function in handleEvent outputs null, the value will not be updated.How do I notify React that the value is changed? Should I create another `useEffect(()=>{}, [value])`?

OR

Can I dispatch an action in `this.rootObject.addEventListener` so I can notify react to re-render some components? Can I use redux in non-react function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see there are 2 options to get this working:
1) Put the part that calculates `position` to the React component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
const handleEvent = event => {
  // convert to ROS coordinates
  const coords = stage.globalToRos(event.stageX, event.stageY);
  const pose = new ROSLIB.Pose({
    position: new ROSLIB.Vector3(coords)
  });
  setValue(pose.position);
};
```

2) Introduce an extra event and listen for it in the component. So that your custom function will look something like this:

```
this.rootObject.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event) {
  // convert to ROS coordinates
  const coords = stage.globalToRos(event.stageX, event.stageY);
  const pose = new ROSLIB.Pose({
    position: new ROSLIB.Vector3(coords)
  });
  // send the goal
  sendGoal(pose);
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newposition', { detail: pose.position }));
}
```

and then add an extra line in your React component:

```
canvas.addEventListener("newposition", (e) => setValue(e.detail), false);
```

In both cases, you will need to add `value` as a second argument to `useEffect` to prevent re-renders.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the second one, because I think I would need to refactor the whole library if I use the first one.

Comment: Tuyakhov
, Thanks, the second one works. But the value does not get updated. why? I can only see e.detail is updating

Comment: Do you mean that the React component doesn't get re-rendered? In that case don't forget that you need to add `value` to `useEffect` as a second argument like this `useEffect(()=>{}, [value])`

Comment: Ok, I figure it out, I need to add another useEffect for the value

Comment: Hey bro.. if I may ask what is this.dispatchEvent? where do I import it from?